# 404 Not Found aspx file but it is there

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, iis-8, plesk

I´m using Plesk and in **Web scripting and statistics** I have *Microsoft ASP support* in ON.

I uploaded a application (which works correctly in my PC) to a directory and it can be shown but when I go to the aspx file it shows me the 404 error (The path is the correct).

I noticed that some files in "shtml" extension are neither shown by the server.

This is my very first time with ASP.NET, ISS8 and Plesk. I don´t know what to do. I will thank you for your help

Comment: so the pages are extension less? In that case it could be a setting (HTTP Handler Extension) in IIS that is not processing request without an extension

Comment: Can I change that via Plesk or code? (I have no access to the server nor SSH)

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: Sorry it didn't, now I'm migrating to Linux Server to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the HTTP Handler Extension. If you have no access to IIS directly, you could do on the web.config:

Open the Web.config file for the application, locate the httpHandlers element of the system.web section and add an entry for the file-name extension

Example:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="SampleHandler" verb="*" 
        path="SampleHandler.new" 
        type="SampleHandler, SampleHandlerAssembly" 
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

For more configuration options please refer to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx
and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Check also the Custom Handler Policy of Plesk that should not be enabled:
https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/securing-plesk/custom-handlers-policy.76787/

Here I've found also another interesting document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/

Scroll down and you'll find a piece of code to add the handlers programmatically, even if I suggest you to add them in your web.config